# Make two images same height without hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, height

Here I have two images. I have the widths of these two img elements exactly how I want it. The gutter between these two elements and their container is exactly how I want it as well.

After applying `vertical-align: top`, I noticed that both of these images automatically determine their own height based on the aspect ratio of the source image. As you can see this means the images end up having the same widths (which I defined explicitly) but different heights by a matter of a dozen pixels or so:

[image: Two images with desired widths (good), but varying heights depending on the source image (bad)]

I was wondering if there is a way to give both of these images the same height without switching them to be background-image's. Also, if this image feed is 'dynamic' how could I explicitly define the height while not knowing the aspect ratio of the image in question?

Comment: well setting the height will distort them....

Comment: Exactly, so I guess what I am wondering is how best to handle this? Would converting them to background-image's be the only option?

Comment: How would converting them to background images make a difference?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/myPZwN you can use object-fit on the img. Not working on IE

Comment: @epascarello Because if I were to strip out these <img> elements and instead use <div>'s with background-image's set, I could explicitly define any width and any height without distorting the image.

Comment: so than you can do the same thing with an image tag, you just hide the overflow of the wrapping div.

Comment: Wow, so you can use background image on img elements? Thanks for that.
As for the OP, try to generate the images all with same height, many frameworks have trouble doing otherwise. A div with overflow hidden is another way to do it, but you never know what will be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that if you set the width and height the same on two differently sized images, at least one of them will be distorted.

[image]

You could quite easily fix this, as long as the images are relatively similar in size. The idea is, you surround the image with a div and give the div the height and width instead of the image. Then give it the CSS `overflow: hidden;` and it will crop off the extra bit of the image. You may also need to give it `display: inline-block;` to get the div's next to each other.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x240">
</div>
```

Or if you want the image vertically centered:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x240">
</div>
```

Comment: @connected_user How's my answer?

Comment: I like this, and yes it is a viable solution. I am curious as to how very tall and narrow images would react to this solution (along side a normal 4:3 aspect ratio image).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using aspect ratios. Format your images to be the same aspect ratio at the minimum before uploading. The other option would be converting to BG images if you can't pre-format.

```
.container {
    padding-top: 100%; /* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
    //padding-top: 75%; /* 4:3 Aspect Ratio */
    //padding-top: 66.66%; /* 3:2 Aspect Ratio */
}
```

Comment: If I wrap <img> elements in a div and then put padding top on the div, it just pushes the image down, the image does not fill the padding?

Comment: I just realized if I set my child img elements to position: absolute I can get them to fit the parent div with the padding

Answer (score 0):

I think another approach would be setting image height and use actual image content as background image with background-size:contain; this way your image will not be distorted and will always fill the size.

```
<img src="blank.gif" style="background-image:url(myImage.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center; background-size:contain;height:300px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would utilize a CSS method of wrapping your images in a container that has `overflow` set to `hidden` which will hide the hanging off pixels.

If you feel people will miss out on part of the image, you could use a css animation like I did below when you hover over it. I use translate3d because it utilizes GPU acceleration in browsers.

```css
main {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
width: 500px;
}

.img-wrap {
overflow:hidden;
height: 15rem;
width: 15rem;
}

.img-wrap>img {
max-width: 500px;
}

.img-wrap:hover>img {
animation: pan 5s;
}

@keyframes pan {
  from {transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
  to {transform:translate3d(-100px,0,0);}
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="img-wrap">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/city/500/600">
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/people/800/700">
</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to set the images as the background of your divs. This will not distort the images as setting the height and width on an img element would. You can then define whether to center it or not.

```css
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/23764/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');"></div>
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/23388/pexels-photo.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');">
</div>
```

Comment: This would solve the problem, but the OP want an answer without using a div with a background image instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have always had this problem, the only solution I found that solves this problem effectively is

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
```

and have the image displayed via backend like php with inline style

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('pathToImage');"></div>
```

Comment: This would solve the problem, but the OP want an answer _without_ using a div with a background image instead.