# Different sizes Images in a 100%-width-row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

i am trying to put several images (five) next to each other in one row. The row should have the width of a 100%. It is important that the images all have the same height e.g.! Is there a way to manage this? I tried several code, e.g. a masonry, but it does not help me with the height of the images.

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Thank you

(I am using Bootstrap if that's any help.)

Comment: Have you got some code that you could post here?

Comment: `img{ height: 100px; width: auto; }`? There's not much more we can offer without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: Actually no, because I can't get it done. I edited my question. The height of the image-bar is irrelevant. Its just important that all images geht shown with the same height. The images also have different aspect ratios. Ill try to visualize is in Photoshop.

Comment: @George Thank you, but that will not work. Im trying to achieve a image-bar with the width of a 100%. Give me a second.

Comment: I added a image to my question. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make two images same height without hardcoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637702/make-two-images-same-height-without-hardcoding)

Comment: No, I need images to be fully shown, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited, new answer.**

The code below should do the job.

Note that I have inserted comments between all the `img` tags in the html, this is to make sure that there is no spacing between the images and is therefore important for the code to work!

Also note that if you change the class of the `div` which contains the images, you will have to change the query selector in the javascript to match this.

Final note: the script is very laggy here in the code snippet. I tried it as an actual webpage and it was not laggy at all, so maybe try that too!

```js
var repeat = true;

window.addEventListener("load", resizeImages);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeImages);

function resizeImages() {

  var i;

  var images = document.querySelectorAll("div.row img");

  var heights = [];
  var widths = [];

  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    heights.push(images[i].offsetHeight);
    widths.push(images[i].offsetWidth);
  }

  var numerator = document.body.clientWidth;

  for (i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
    numerator *= heights[i];
  }

  var denominator = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {

    var thisItem = widths[i];

    for (i2 = 0; i2 < heights.length; i2++) {

      if (i != i2) {
        thisItem *= heights[i2];
      }
    }

    denominator += thisItem;
  }

  var height = numerator / denominator;

  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].height = height;
  }

  if (repeat) {
    repeat = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      resizeImages();
    }, 300)


  }


}
```

```css
div.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg" alt=""><!--
        --><img style="padding-left:5px;" src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w600/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png" alt=""><!--
        --><img src="http://www.andysowards.com/blog/assets/8-Best-Websites-That-Will-Hone-Your-Programming-Skills-7-1024x538.png" alt="">
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid this would mess up the ratio of my images. I added a image to my question. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @nwde Yes, I understand now. I don't see how this could be achieved without javascript, I could try a new solution now if that would be acceptable?

Comment: I would be very glad!

Comment: @nwde I have done it now! My code just uses some random images that come up when you google 'stackoverflow', you can just replace them with as many of your own images as you like.

Comment: Please ask if you want me to explain any part of the javascript :)

Comment: This is great, can I buy you a coffee? Thank you!

Just two questions if that ok for you:
+ Is it possible for the code to accept a padding-right or left added to one image e.g.?
+ how would I have to approach, if I need to have several rows with different images and different aspect ratios? 

Ty!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203258/discussion-between-nwde-and-run-script).

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS Grid for your implementation. `.row` is 100% width and each image can have its own custom scaling if need be.

Be aware, images are hard make constant because each image will come with its own ratio and size. 
You can use `background-size` to set image property to your liking.

The `background-size` CSS property sets the size of the element's background image. The image can be left to its natural size, stretched, or constrained to fit the available space.

Hope the example below helps.

Reference `background-size`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Reference `CSS Grid`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
img {
     height: 130px;
     width: 100%;
}

.row{  
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
 /* If each individual picture column need modification*/
 /* grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 200px 15px 10%; */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/8447_7961096220_79eb4fb07c_c_640_360_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_40670884373_757596f5d1_b_640_360_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_47957578362_73f1562d77_z_640_360_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_46970967485_3456a6be5f_z_640_360_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/2544_3722368834_5584ab3bc1_z_640_360_nofilter.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: The images have been squashed.

Comment: The images will react to the screen size, unless a certain width and height is applied.

Comment: What I mean is that regardless of the images' original format, they have been resized to fit into a square, squashing the images. See my answer for a possible javascript solution to this.

Comment: @Run_Script Interesting approach. If this person is only using CSS, they would need to put the images in a block. Then each block can be modified or every block in a row could have the same properties. The question itself is not clear with the approach.